# Unable to revive connection [Kibana]

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, kibana-7

I have a Elasticsearch instance in dev mode. My Elasticsearch config is following,

```
cluster.name: "logparser"
node.master: true
node.data: true
node.ingest: true
node.ml: false
path.data: /storage/elasticsearch
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
network.host: _local_
xpack.security.enabled: true
xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled: true
xpack.security.http.ssl.keystore.path: certs/elasticsearch.p12
xpack.security.http.ssl.truststore.path: certs/elasticsearch.p12
```

Following is my Kibana configuration,

```
server.port: 5601
server.host: 172.16.10.10
server.name: "logparser.akash.pub"
elasticsearch.hosts: ["https://127.0.0.1:9200"]
elasticsearch.username: "kibana"
elasticsearch.password: "blabla"
elasticsearch.ssl.certificateAuthorities: [ "/etc/kibana/certs/elastic-ca.pem" ]
xpack.security.enabled: true
```

For your information, I have created `.pem` file from the `kibana.p12` file which created from `elastic-stack-ca.p12`

My Problem is ,

```
Oct 11 01:24:19 logparser kibana: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-10-10T19:24:19Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":3862,"message":"Unable to revive connection: https://127.0.0.1:9200/"}
Oct 11 01:28:18 logparser kibana: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-10-10T19:28:18Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":3862,"message":"No living connections"}
```

I can reach Elasticsearch with the Kibana's credential,

```
curl -kA "Mozilla" -L "https://kibana:blabla@localhost:9200"                                                                                                                                
{
"name" : "logparser.akash.pub",
"cluster_name" : "logparser",
"cluster_uuid" : "eR48rtysQHWTa89ZxXBrNQ",
"version" : {
"number" : "7.4.0",
"build_flavor" : "default",
"build_type" : "rpm",
"build_hash" : "22e1767283e61a198cb4db791ea66e3f11ab9910",
"build_date" : "2019-09-27T08:36:48.569419Z",
"build_snapshot" : false,
"lucene_version" : "8.2.0",
"minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
"minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
},
"tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Current network status,

```
[root@logparser]# netstat -tulpn 
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 172.16.10.10:5601       0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3862/node           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1135/sshd           
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:9200          :::*                    LISTEN      3370/java           
tcp6       0      0 ::1:9200                :::*                    LISTEN      3370/java           
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:9300          :::*                    LISTEN      3370/java           
tcp6       0      0 ::1:9300                :::*                    LISTEN      3370/java           
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1135/sshd
```

#### How to resolve the problem?